# Why I cannot run PowerShell 2 from Cygwin?

Tags: powershell, cygwin

I have PowerShell 3 installed, and I need to run PowerShell 2 from Cygwin

```
$ PowerShell -Version 2
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Michael> $host.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

But as you see it is still running PowerShell 3.

Do you have any ideas what am I doing wrong?

If you curious why I need to run PowerShell from Cygwin, it is because of the git hooks I am writing.
 To develop server-side hooks I write PowerShell script, and because of the problem described above, I cannot use my nice trick with breakpoints

UPD: I am using Cygwin 1.7.11 terminal on Windows 8

UPD: I can even run cmd in between to make sure that parameters are passed properly

```
$ cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Michael>PowerShell -Version 2
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Michael> $host.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as expected for me.

[image]

You might have to give more context to see why this is not working. Only reason I can think of is somehow the `-Version 2.0` param is not being passed to powershell.

Comment: Please see update I made in a question. The same issue I have when I run cygwin -> cmd -> PowerShell -Version 2

Do you really have PowerShell 3 installed?

Comment: @mnaoumov - I am on Windows 8 with Powershell 3.0. How do you run cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Cygwin doesn't pass parameters to Powershell.exe as one would expect? Check the command line Powershell.exe has been invoked with. You can use the Win32_Process WMI class for that. In order to avoid confusion with other Powershell instances, get process and parent process ids too. Use the same query to get Cygwin's pid or just use task manager. Like so,

```
gwmi win32_process -filter "Name = 'powershell.exe'" | select commandline, processid, parentprocessid | ft -AutoSize
```

Comment: Please see update I made in a question. I used the command you suggested, and I see that commandline is correct "PowerShell -Version 2"