# interactive powershell from Cygwin

Tags: powershell, cygwin

I cannot run PowerShell.exe interactively in a Cygwin rxvt or mintty terminal. Seems any session using a /dev/tty? or /dev/pts? pseudo terminal device.  An instance using the junky windows console device /dev/console or /dev/cons? will work.

```
cygstart /bin/bash -li
```

launches the console version in the cruddy Windows Command Prompt which is the only place I can get an interactive PowerShell.

[image: Console]

Works.  Rxvt doesnt:
[image: rxvt]

Nor does mintty:
[image: mintty]

I've tried all the `echo -e | powershell.exe` and `powershell.exe </dev/null`

I'm assuming when I see answers on Stackoverflow on this they are using Console's ... or am I missing something?

[Why I cannot run PowerShell 2 from Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107544/why-i-cannot-run-powershell-2-from-cygwin) seems to run fine, just gets powershell v3 when he wants v2 ... wish I had that problem.

---

I've developed a powershell wrapper to call powershell scripts and commands from a Cygwin terminal session but cannot get the interactive option to work (if you give the wrapper no script or commands then you want to go interactive).  see https://bitbucket.org/jbianchi/powershell/wiki/ for info on the wrapper script. It works for most powershell.exe calls and even acts like a "she-bang" if used in the first line of the ps1 script.

Comment: Can't help but wonder why on earth you would want to do this instead of writing a shell script. I mean you're already in bash which IMO is much more powerful than PowerShell. Starting PowerShell from Cygwin Bash is like starting VisualStudio from Eclipse. But I'll demur.

Comment: First off, I hate "why do you need to do that" answers... Have you ever searched for a solution to a problem and find someone who explains the same problem and look through the answers to see others saying "why would you want to do that?" His/her answer may or may not be the same as your but you finally found someone talking about the same problem and the "answers" are "Why would you want to do that" !!! grrr!!! but OK, I'll answer that....

Comment: I have many powershell scripts that do vSphere/PowerCLI stuff and many that do WinAD calls (either built in or Quest calls).  I would like my bash script looping through hosts to be able to call powercli and set a vmWare attribute on the host or check what its reporting as the GuestOS or any number of things.  Real Answer: Isn't the point to best use the tools to get the job done?  Ruby, python, bash, perl, awk,... why not powershell? And if PowerShell, why not give me an interactive shell?

Comment: Yes I have but it was a comment, not an answer. But since you mentioned using the best tools, you haven't established why PowerShell is the best tool for anything. Basically you've got PS scripts you don't want to convert to Bash but you want to still use Bash anyway. Whatever, fine, but don't pretend it's optimal.

Comment: ok, gotta agree that PS is not the best but if you want to script/automate windows admin, its the only answer (lets happily forget VisualBasic/JScript, please;) its not optimal, bit we're also here to talk about how to call powershell in a bash shell via cygwin/mingw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today, typing powershell at a Cygwin bash prompt just works.

Comment: Agreed.  I think since Win10 and PS5.0 and the improvements to the console (I think they do readline and other linuxish things)... it just works now

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've found is to use http://sergeybelous.com/ (main site) [Proxy32](http://sergeybelous.com/index1.html) `proxywinconsole.exe` program. If this program is in the path, my [poweshell.bash wrapper](https://bitbucket.org/jbianchi/powershell) will call it which will let you work interactively with PowerShell.

Comment: site layout changed. looks like he is changing the site.  download is at http://www.sergeybelous.com/proxy/proxywinconsole.exe. fixed link to point to main www root

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run powershell inside cygwin/babun, follow https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56#c64 . Bascilly, downloard or compile https://github.com/rprichard/winpty, copy it to your $PATH and then run

```
console.exe powershell
```

This also works with batch scripts that invoke powershell inside.

Comment: If I cannot use RXVT with Cygwin, I'd give up on Windows and go to a linux desktop ... but the Windows desktop is what I have to support.

Answer (score 1):

First Install cygwin in your system. 
After that type bash on powershell terminal and you can access cygwin terminal.

```
PS C:\Users\username\1and1> bash
username@LWMT-14R25Q2:/mnt/c/Users/username/1and1$
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't answer your question, but maybe I can help you a little further on your way with this:

I believe this is related to this issue, as discussed on the [MinTTY Issue #56](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56).
It goes into great detail as to how common cmd.exe shell applications work and interact, so much as they detail how common unix applications using their TTY abstraction layer work differently than Windows command line applications.

Answer (score -2):

Script for running powershell on Cygwin minty:

```
blahblah@blahblahbin $ cat pwrshl
#!/usr/bin/bash if [[ ! -f "$1" ]] then
        echo "Usage: $0 <PowerShellScriptFile>"
        exit fi

echo "\n" | powershell -Command "& {$(<$1)}"
```

Comment: How is this an answer?  My whole point is when you don't give it a script it needs to go interactive and this is the part that doesnt work.  Your script checks to see if there is an arg given and does not run w/o ... your missing the whole point! read the question and notice it says "interactive"!